# Image classification model for pet food

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, classification, fast-ai

I am making a CNN to detect different types of kibbles (pet food). I want the model to be able to tell you wether a picture of kibbles is of dog kibbles or cat kibbles. I have about 500 images belonging to each class. I used a pre-trained model (resnet.34) and fastai in python to make my model. I am wondering whether or not I need to do some sort of image segmentation in order for the model to be accurate. Like having the model identify each individual kibble as a different object. Because at the moment, the model might be making predictions on attributes other than the actual kibbles. I know with tensorflow you can visualize the different objects that exist in an image. Not sure how that is done with fastai. I'll attach a few images of the data that I am using in my training set.
[[image: kibble_train][1]]
[image: kibbles_train]

Answer (score 0):

No you don't *need* to use segmentation. Chances are that if there is signal in your data, the CNN will learn it and bias won't be too much of a problem.

If you're afraid that other elements (e.g., the kind of bowl) might bias your algorithm, I think you could do many things before segmentation (which is a *very* strenuous task). For instance, you could crop the middle square of the picture. Then, only the kibbles would be visible.

That being said, there is still very little information that could bias your algorithm. If you look at the popular cats and dogs dataset, there is a lot of unnecessary background, yet it's an easy classification task.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you likely do not need image segmentation for this problem, it definitely seems like classification should be able to handle it. I agree with Nicolas that cropping might help, but perhaps presenting a mix of cropped/non-cropped images for training would help the model to focus on the kibble itself?

I'd also look into [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) and/or other adjustments that could be applied to the images before training/prediction is performed on them. One thing I notice in your sample images is the color differences don't stand out a ton. Histogram equalization will increase global contrast in the image and makes it easier for the model to pick up on differences. I'd look into image enhancement like this before moving to more complex model options, as they're far faster to apply.